# Unable to install firebase-tools by npm on MAC OSX 10.12.6 (ERROR : Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...x","firebase":"~1.0.1)

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-tools, firebase-cli

I am currently using **node version 10.10.0** and **npm version 6.4.1** Trying to install firebase CLI to work on cloud functions for the firebase project already created. It is working fine on other systems but is unable to install firebase-tools on my MAC. I have also installed a fresh version of node in hope of getting this error rectified but it did not help. I also **tried using 'sudo' and '--force' with npm** to install but it also did not help. Here is a complete log of the error i got. Please help
Here is the error log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'firebase-tools' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.10.0
4 verbose npm-session 402be1d1b21d5c2d
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-tools 297ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for firebase-tools@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...x","firebase":"~1.0.1'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 477ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...x","firebase":"~1.0.1'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50)
11 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
12 verbose cwd /Users/techienimi
13 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
14 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "firebase-tools"
15 verbose node v10.10.0
16 verbose npm  v6.4.1
17 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...x","firebase":"~1.0.1'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on these lines:

```
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-tools 297ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for firebase-tools@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...x","firebase":"~1.0.1'
```

It sounds like your npm cache might be corrupt.  Try deleting the directory `.npm` in your home directory to reset it.

Or, you could try to [run a command to reset the cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/try-clearing-the-npm-cache).